# What is the logic behind stoning satan?

Tags: shaitan, hajj, rajm

Many years ago, I was living in a Islamic country and I was student of Islamic religion, because I wanted to be a Muslim by heart and by knowledge, I did not want to be inherited Muslim because my father was Muslim and I must follow him. I am now living in a non-Islamic country and so far, using the guidance of Quran and Hadith, I researched and found the logic behind every commandment of haram and halal. One thing that really bothers me and I could not find any answer is that stoning sculpture of Satan during Hajj Pilgrimage.  It is just a sculpture. I see people stoning it. It somehow does not make any sense for me.

What is the logic behind stoning satan?

I do not know whether stoning satan is farz or sunnah or why it should be done. What could Muslim benefit from it. I would be grateful if you could elaborate on the logic and basis of this stoning practice.

Someone told me that this practice is just for the indoctrinating purposes. Same way like for dry ablution when there is no water, at least you do something so that you indoctrinate your self that at least you did something than nothing to became clean and do your pray. I get the point on the dry ablution but my brain does not work on the stoning of Satan

Comment: As a former Student of Islamic religion you should know about the hajj much more than many of us as it would be among the first subjects you've studied. As any fiqh book beginns with the acts of worship 'ibadat.

Comment: Note that in almost all hajj rituals we follow (or remember) acts that have been performed by Hajar the wife of the Prophet Ibrahim (pbuh). And in islamic fiqh we don't speak about stoning the devil or satan rather then throwing jamaraat (carbuncle or little stones). And it is a mandatory act for completing hajj (as it is among the last acts of hajj). It could be regarded as a symbolic act of throwing away all former bad deeds and acts as hajj is said to purify a soul, as when you perform it well you might be consider to have a new/white register.

Answer (score 2):

First of all trying to find a logic or scientific explanation to religion is not always good. Science is a progressive information. New evidences can prove old theory or rule may not be correct.Still, If you need a reasonable explanation to  stoning of Satan, this may help:

> [Actions influence attitudes](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Actions_influence_attitudes)
>
> [cognitive dissonance: changing attitudes to justify behavior](http://www.psypress.co.uk/smithandmackie/resources/topic.asp?topic=ch08-tp-01)
>
> "The theory of cognitive dissonance states that when people become aware that their freely chosen actions violate important or relevant attitudes, the inconsistency produces an uncomfortable state of arousal called dissonance, which motivates people to change their initial attitudes to make them consistent with their behavior. For cognitive dissonance to occur, it is important that the attitude is important and self-relevant."

In psychology, actions affect attitudes or beliefs. So stoning satan is an action. Even there maybe no satan there. But you symbolically stone him. At this point your brain work like this: "I stoned satan, I can stone only bad things, So Satan is bad, and after stoning him, how can I do what Satan ask me to do."

At this point your action change your belief and you don't do sin as much as you did before.

[Stoning satan](https://islamqa.info/en/34420) one of the important parts of Hajj. You can find any [resources](https://www.al-islam.org/hajj-pilgrimage-dr-ali-shariati/three-idols) easily to explain it in Islamic perspective.

And you can also find [some resources](http://www.quran-islam.org/faq/stoning_during_hajj_(P1136).html) that claim [stoning satan is wrong](http://www.quran-islam.org/main_topics/islam/pillars/al-hajj_(P1195).html)

Answer (score 2):

Its a ritual. I'd rather not get into the discussion of why rituals are carried out ... The Hajj enacts actions of Prophet Abraham and his wife Hagar. Specifically the stoning ritual is about the [Sacrifice of Prophet Ishmael](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binding_of_Isaac).

Prophet Abraham had a dream in which Allah commanded him to sacrifice his young son (Ishmael) in His name as a test of his devotion. When Abraham was going to perform the sacrifice Satan tried to dissuade him at three spots. Abraham threw stones at the devil to repel him and Muslims enact this *rejection of the devil* by throwing stones at three pillars.

[**Tafsir Ibn Kathir**  on  37:103](http://www.alim.org/library/quran/AlQuran-tafsir/TIK/37/99)

> ```
> Imam Ahmad recorded that Ibn `Abbas, may Allah be pleased with him,
> said, "When the rituals were enjoined upon Ibrahim, peace be upon him,
> the Shaytan appeared to him at the Mas`a and raced with him, but
> Ibrahim got there first. Then Jibril, upon him be peace, took him to
> Jamrat Al-`Aqabah and the Shaytan appeared to him, so he stoned him
> with seven pebbles until he disappeared. Then he appeared him at
> Al-Jamrah Al-Wusta and he stoned him with seven pebbles. Then he laid
> him prostrate on his face. Isma`il, peace be upon him, was wearing a
> white shirt, and he said, `O my father, I do not have any garment in
> which I can be shrouded apart from this; take it off me so that you
> can shroud me in it.' He started to take it off, then he was called
> from behind.
> ```